# The Bootstrap carousel

Tags: carousel

I’m using bootstrap slideshow in my app and I’m using some images and videos to slide, but the video is star playing automatically immediately when page got loaded.  Can anyone help me how to fix this issue?

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="6"></li>
    </ol>
    <!-- Carousel items -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item">
            <img src="/Content/Images/image-01" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="/Content/Images/image-02" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="/Content/Images/image-03" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="/Content/Images/image-04.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="/Content/Images/image-05.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <img src="/Content/Images/image-06.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
                <iframe src="/Content/Images/test-vedio.mp4" width="960" height="400" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post some sample code ?

Answer (score 0):

put your video inside a video element so you can manipulate its attributes:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp